# Make [osx-yosemite] the canonical Yosemite tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

There are three tags related to OS X Yosemite on the main site:

1. [osx-yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx-yosemite) (763 questions)
2. [osx-yosemite10.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx-yosemite10.10) (86 questions)
3. [osx-yosemite-beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx-yosemite-beta) (60 questions)

Tags for the previous versions of OS X all follow the first style, with a handful of synonyms. I think we should likewise combine the Yosemite tags into [osx-yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx-yosemite), and either burninate or synonymize the other two tags (I don't know what would be more appropriate for SO.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've made [osx-yosemite10.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx-yosemite10.10) a synonym of [osx-yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx-yosemite), but held off on doing the same for [osx-yosemite-beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx-yosemite-beta). The beta tag has many questions in it that might only pertain to the beta version of the OS, and we might not want to group those in with the main tag.

For the beta tag, I'd recommend finding all the questions that are still relevant to the released OS and retagging them to remove the beta and replace it with the main tag. For the remaining questions, we might look at closing them as "can no longer reproduce" if they aren't applicable to the released OS.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable compromise.