# Merge [osx-yosemite] and [yosemite]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

There are 3 tags related to OS X Yosemite:

- [osx-yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx-yosemite) (1920 questions)
- [yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yosemite) (210 questions)
- [osx-yosemite-beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx-yosemite-beta) (48 questions)

OS X related tags follow `[osx-*]` style, with a handful of synonyms (similar to proposed one).
I think we should make [yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yosemite) a synonym for [osx-yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx-yosemite), because literally all of these questions are OS X Yosemite-related.
We don't need to touch [osx-yosemite-beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx-yosemite-beta), as it was stated in [this request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281396/make-osx-yosemite-the-canonical-yosemite-tag).

Comment: How many of those questions are on-topic that *require* this tag?

Comment: @Makoto I think most of them are on-topic, but not necessarily require this tag. Maybe just [tag:osx] would be better

Comment: @Makoto also I think clean-up of OS X Yosemite-related questions is beyond my request. It can be done as a separate request.

Comment: Well, since you want to merge things, it makes sense to clean them up too while we're here.